# re-arrange columns in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a script which refers to certain columns by indices and not names. Is there a way for a new data set which has the same columns to be re-arranged in a way that in would fit the original data frame for which the script was written?

I would like df2 to have the same order of columns as df1 below

```
age = c(20,30,22,32,10)
gender = c('M','F','M','F','M')
name = c('A','B','C','D','E')

df1 = data.frame(age,name,gender)
df2 = data.frame(gender, name, age)
> df1
  age name gender
1  20    A      M
2  30    B      F
3  22    C      M
4  32    D      F
5  10    E      M
> df2
  gender name age
1      M    A  20
2      F    B  30
3      M    C  22
4      F    D  32
5      M    E  10
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just do

```
 df2[names(df1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
> df2[, names(df1)]
  age name gender
1  20    A      M
2  30    B      F
3  22    C      M
4  32    D      F
5  10    E      M
```

Answer (score 2):

If you decide to start using the `data.table` package, there is a `setcolorder` function that works like so:

```
setcolorder(df2,names(df1))
```

From `?setcolorder`:

> `setcolorder` reorders the columns of data.table, by reference, to the new order provided.

You can read more about what's mean by "by reference" [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started), but suffice to say you should prefer this if you've got a *large* `data.frame` because it will be faster.