# Arrange column order in R data frame inside a list

Tags: r, dataframe, list, tidyverse

I have a list containing multiple data frames. Each data frames have the same column names except one or more columns that have other variables. I took this example data frame from another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31348171/re-arrange-columns-in-a-data-frame-in-r).

```
age <- c(20,30,22,32,10)
gender <- c('M','F','M','F','M')
name <- c('A','B','C','D','E')
salary <- c('800','400','300','670','790')
resident <- c('X','Y','Z','W','U')
ownership <- c('Yes','No','Yes','No','No')


df1 <- data.frame(age,name,gender,salary)
df2 <- data.frame(gender,name,age,resident,ownership)
> df1
  age name gender salary
1  20    A      M   800
2  30    B      F   400
3  22    C      M   300
4  32    D      F   670
5  10    E      M   790
> df2
  gender name age resident ownership
1      M    A  20       X        Yes
2      F    B  30       Y        No
3      M    C  22       Z        Yes
4      F    D  32       W        No
5      M    E  10       U        No


mylist <- list(df1, df2)
```

How do I rearrange each data frame inside the list so that there is a fixed mutual column sequence across the dataset (name, gender, age) followed by other columns that are not mutually shared across the data frame?

I know how to arrange column for each data frame but not sure how to do it for a list. And how to do it without naming the column each time.

```
#if I rearrange column individually
df1 <- df1[, c("name", "gender", "age", "salary")]

#if I try by naming the mutual column, this will only select not arrange
col_arrangement <- c("name", "gender", "age")
df1 <- df1[, names(df1) %in% c(col_arrangement, "salary")]
```

The reason these data frame are inside a list was to write them all later to individual excel workbook (I was told working with R list is better than making changes to individual data frame, but I'm not proficient with list at all). What I sadly do each time is rearrange columns inside each sheet in the Excel workbook.

My desired output, a list containing data frames with arranged columns.

```
> df1
  name  age  gender salary
1  A    20    M    800
2  B    30    F    400
3  C    22    M    300
4  D    32    F    670
5  E    10    M    790
> df2
  name  age  gender resident ownership
1  A    20    M     X        Yes
2  B    30    F     Y        No
3  C    22    M     Z        Yes
4  D    32    F     W        No
5  E    10    M     U        No
```

Comment: How is `c("name","gender","age")` derived? If you get the common names in each `dfN`, then that order is arbitrary. Or are you just manually specifying that ahead of time?

Comment: I just manually specify it because the common column need to be in that order

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function you need is `relocate()` from the `dplyr` package, iterating the list with `map` (`purrr` package) or `lapply` (base R). Since you tagged `tidyverse`, I'll use `map()` in my answer.

To find out common column names between the dataframes, you can use:

```r
reduce(map(mylist, names), intersect) ## thanks @thelatemail in the comment
[1] "age"    "name"   "gender"
```

But since you already have `col_arrangement` defined, I directly included it in my answer below:

```r
library(tidyverse)

col_arrangement <- c("name", "gender", "age")

map(mylist, ~ relocate(.x, any_of(col_arrangement)))

[[1]]
  name gender age salary
1    A      M  20    800
2    B      F  30    400
3    C      M  22    300
4    D      F  32    670
5    E      M  10    790

[[2]]
  name gender age resident ownership
1    A      M  20        X       Yes
2    B      F  30        Y        No
3    C      M  22        Z       Yes
4    D      F  32        W        No
5    E      M  10        U        No
```